# Check if the record is created in flow entry condition

Tags: visual-workflow

In record-triggered flows that run when a record is created or updated, if I try adding entry conditions based on a field change, then the flow no longer works on record creation.

How can I set the entry conditions such that the flow will run when certain fields change OR the record is created?

For example, if I want the flow to run whenever an account's parent is changed and I want the same logic to run when the account is created in the first place.

To be clear, I mean entry conditions pictured below, not a decision element. The goal is to prevent entering the flow in the first place.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use formulas (e.g. `ISNEW()`) in the *individual field* entry conditions for a flow, but there are a few hacks for checking if the record is new within the entry conditions.

1. In a before-save flow (i.e. "fast field updates"), you can check if the **Record ID is null**.
   [image: record id is null]
2. In an after-save flow (i.e. "actions and related records"), you can check if the **Created Date was changed**.
   [image: created date is changed]

These can be used in conjunction with any of the other filters available, which allows your flow to handle more nuanced situations. For example, if I want to send an email when:

1. a record already has an agent and the status *becomes* "pending".
2. or when a record is created with both an agent and "pending" status.

[image: entry condition example]

---

The Summer '22 release introduced [formulas as flow entry conditions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_use_formulas_as_flow_entry_conditions.htm&type=5&release=238), which allows for the usage of [`ISNEW()`](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_isnew.htm&type=5). As an entry formula, the example above could become:

```
AND(
  OR(
    ISNEW(), 
    ISCHANGED({!$Record.Status__c})
  ),
  ISPICKVAL({!$Record.Status__c}, 'Pending'),
  NOT(ISBLANK({!$Record.Agent__c}))
)
```